# Virtual Directory setup with no IIS

Tags: .net, iis

Is there a way to create an environment with multiple folders that act like a virtual directory without messing with IIS? 
For example, I have FTP access to a site, lets say www.example.com. I need to create a folder in the root called /app1 where I will deploy a .Net MVC 4 application to. Is it possible to setup something in the root that will redirect the call to www.example.com/app1 as if app1 was a virtual directory setup on IIS and deploy my MVC application straight to the /app1 folder?

So, when I need to create another .Net MVC site I would create another folder in the root called /app2 and deploy to it.

Comment: It's possible to set something up that will do this; it's called IIS. :-) The web server is what does that redirection that you want - why are you asking how to replace the functionality of your web server with something that provides the functionality of your web server?

Comment: Ken, I totally agree with you but I had someone requesting me to do something like this. I am just trying to make sure that it is not possible to do it this way and that the best way would be to have separate virtual directories setup on IIS.